# Suppressing OWASP Zed Attack Proxy issues

Tags: jenkins, owasp, zap

Let's say I'm getting the same issue on every website scanned in OWASP Zed Attack Proxy(ZAP). How do I go about, if I want to suppress this issues?

Answer (score 0):

You can just disable the rule which raises the issue. For passive scan rules see Options/Passive Scan Rules (change the threshold) and for active scan rules use the Scan Policy Manager.
ZAP has *very* fine control over the scan rules :)